# How to plot hyperbolic function using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot this Ewan webster function using tikz:

[image]

The above image is generated in python using numpy function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
a = 0
b = 2
x = np.linspace(a,b,points)
y = np.exp(x)* np.sin(100*np.cosh(x)) 
plt.plot(x,y)
```

But my plot is not coming as expected. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2]

  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4) node[above] {$f(x)$};

  \draw[color=red]    plot (\x,\x)             node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x))}) node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm how to correct that?

Comment: @Teepeemm sorry it was 100 in place of 1 before the cosh; I edited it.

Comment: What is "Ewan webster function"? There is also an incoherence between your graph (y seems to be positive, more precisely ≈ 1 for x=0) and your equation: for x=0, cosh(x)=cosh(0)=1, and sin(100cosh(0))=sin(100)≈-0.506, and so, for x=0, exp(x)sin(100cosh(x))≈-0.506<0, not 1. The argument of sin must be in radians, because with degree, there isn't so much oscillations with x between 0 and 2 (the argument of sin is between 0 and 100cosh(2)≈376). With radians you obtain ≈60 oscillations (in fact less because 100cosh(x)<=376), with degrees, around 1 oscilllation. So can you check you exact equation?

Comment: @quark67 I have checked and updated the image as well as the code which was used to plot this function. Thanks

Comment: I searched and found no such `Ewan webster function` in mathematics. If that is true, please don't use that name to avoiding confusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have corrected your code.

You need to specify that you uses radian in the argument of the sinus (it's with the `r`).

I have modified the x-scale and y-scale (because the exponential grows rapidly).

I have added the `smooth` key, so the curve is smoothed, not drawn with straight lines betweens the points.

I have augmented the samples to 500 points (by default, it's 25).

But I have to restrict the plotting domain to `0:1.7` instead of `0:2` because unless that, Ti*k*Z complains about **dimension too large** errors.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:1.70,samples=500,smooth,xscale=3,yscale=0.5]

  \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$f(x)$};

  \draw[color=orange] plot (\x,{exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)}) node[right] 
      {$f(x) = \mathrm e^x\sin\left(100\cosh\left(x\right)\right)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the **dimension too large** errors, instead of using Ti*k*Z, we can use **pgfplots**.

Here is a first attempt:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=500,domain=0:2]
\addplot[orange]plot (\x, {exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, it's not perfect at the end.

We can split the draw in two domains, the latter domain for x between 1.2 and 2 using a more dense sampling.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[orange,samples=500,domain=0:1.5]plot (\x, {exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)});
\addplot[orange,samples=1000,domain=1.5:2]plot (\x, {exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

We obtain a better plotting:

[image]

We can customize the presentation:

```latex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,axis y line=left,xlabel=$x$,legend pos=north west]
\addplot[orange,samples=500,domain=0:1.5]plot (\x, {exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)});
\addplot[orange,samples=1000,domain=1.5:2]plot (\x, {exp(\x)*sin(100*cosh(\x) r)});
\legend{\textcolor{orange}{$\mathrm e^x\sin\left(100\cosh\left(x\right)\right)$}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Asymptote has more controls on mathematical graphs. In this case, the number of sample points `n=1000` and the join type `Hermite` works quite well together.

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
import graph;
unitsize(5cm,4mm);
real a=0,b=2;
real y(real x) {return exp(x)*sin(100*cosh(x));}
path gr=graph(y,a,b,n=1000,Hermite);
draw(gr,magenta);
axes();

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```